# hapijs catbox-redis -- server returns to command prompt

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

**The issue:**

From this simple "tutorial" style code, when I start the server, it prints `server started on 8080` to the console and then ends.  No additional errors or input is provided.

*(...more debugging info after the code...)*

```
var hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new hapi.Server(8080, "localhost", {
    cache: {
        engine: require('catbox-redis'),
        options: {
            host: "10.99.99.99",  // fake ip
            partition: 'hello',   
            password: "soopersekret"  // not really, but you get the idea
        }
    } });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('hello world');
    } });

server.start(function () { console.log('server started on 8080'); });
```

**Additional debugging attempted:**

1. using `redis-cli` on the dev system, we can connect to the host and use the `AUTH` password to successfully view keys, so connectivity seems OK.
2. running a local instance of redis on the dev system, commenting out the `host`, the server starts up and serves content
3. commenting out the entire `cache` configuration section results in content being served as expected

Believing that connectivity and configuration are not the issues, and with such a ridiculously simple app, and without any other feedback from the app about what might be the problem we're stumped.  :(

versions: node 0.10.30; hapi 6.4.0; catbox 3.1.0; catbox-redis 1.0.4

Comment: Have you tried dropping the partition? Also I think you might need the `port` as well unless your redis instance is on 6379.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get an error object in the callback you pass to server.start;

```
server.start(function (err) { 
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err); 
  }
  console.log('server started on 8080');
});
```